# What are the conventions to using the Sidekiq gem in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

We are currently using delayed_job to send emails but are moving to sidekiq for another reason.  This is how I will be using sideqik to send emails:

```
  UserMailer.delay.welcome_email(user)
```

Why wouldn't I create an entirely new worker.rb for this since a worker is sending the email?  When do I actually need to create a worker.rb file?

Thanks

Comment: It's not totally clear what you are asking. As far as I know Sidekiq doesn't require a worker.rb file. Have you seen http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the delay functionality is built into Sidekiq so you don't need to create a worker for that.